# Opencart how to related 2 options in a product

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

Hello I have the following problem.

I have a product with two different options, size and color. But I didn't know how to related this options when someone is buying a product. For example.
I have 4 T-shirt on my inventory 
2 Blue T-shirt size S
1 Green T-shirt size L
1 Yellow T-shirt size XL

I configured the product with these requirement options (size and color), but for example a customer can buy a T-shirt size XL color blue and that's wrong because I didn't have a way to related the color with the size. Any Idea, plugin or suggestion???

Thanks I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opencart: How to relate product options (like size and color)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954116/opencart-how-to-relate-product-options-like-size-and-color)

Answer (score 0):

take a look in the extension store for dependent options. that seems to be the thing you are after

Answer (score -1):

There is an extension designed for this [Related options for OpenCart](http://liveopencart.com/related-options/)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.