# Opencart: How to relate product options (like size and color)?

Tags: php, opencart, shopping-cart, product

I'm using opencart version 1.5.5.1 for our website. I need to add more than one option for products. For example: I need to show shirts of sizes- Large/Medium/Small and colors White/Black/Blue/Red/Green etc. By default opencart allows us to add separate quantities for each color and size.

How can I mention that we've 5 Large Shirts of Blue Color, 3 Medium Shirts of White Color etc. ?

Please help. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

I guess this would only be possible if You create an options for *size x color* combinations only. Customer then would have to pick the desired size and color in one option, like:

```
S, black (+ $0.00)     - 3 pieces
S, green (+ $0.00)     - 1 piece
M, black (+ $0.00)     - 7 pieces
M, red (+ $0.00)       - 11 pieces
M, blue (+ $0.00)      - 2 pieces
L, black (+ $0.00)     - 1 pieces
L, black (+ $0.00)     - 2 pieces
XL, pink (+ $0.00)     - 200 pieces
```

I believe this could be hard to maintain but it would much easier and cheaper than implementing such a dependency into OpenCart. But it is a nice idea to think about (maybe Daniel Kerr should more than us...).

---

**EDIT:** according to the comment: in that case only solution is to have different product per color (or size) and then only pick up the desired size (color) option... In that case You would have much more products but You would be able to restrict each's color pieces per concrete size (or vice versa)...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, we need both options selectable in frontend.

Comment: I also thought the same, but it's not a good idea to repeat the product for color/size!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using a standard install. There is a commercial modification that can do this and you can find it [here](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=2833). It's called OpenStock and I believe it does what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can try this extension: [Option To Product](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=14468)

It does exactly what you need.

Comment: Hi drcoder,

Thanks a lot for the comment. It's a very nice and userful extension. I've added a comment in your extension page. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

[Related options for OpenCart](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=14763) can help you

Comment: Russian-speaking users can get it here 
[Связанные опции для OpenCart](http://liveopencart.ru/opencart-moduli-shablony/moduli/prochee/svyazannyie-optsii "Связанные / зависимые опции для OpenCart (ОпенКарт) / ocStore")