# How to set global option IDs for product options in Opencart 3?

Tags: javascript, opencart

I'm using opencart 3. And I am using product options for all products. I suppose to write a javascript to hide/show three product options when selecting another product option in all products. The option id are different for every product. How to add global id/global class for options.

for product 1:

```
<input name="option[1118]" value="" id="input-option1118" class="form-control" style="display: none;" type="text">
```

for product 2:

```
<input name="option[1229]" value="1229" id="input-option1229" class="form-control" style="display: block;" type="text">
```

Javascript code

```
$('#product #input-option1228').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
var waistDiv = document.getElementById("option-1229");
var waistInput = document.getElementById("input-option1229");
var hipDiv = document.getElementById("option-1231");
var hipInput = document.getElementById("input-option1231");
var heightDiv = document.getElementById("option-1232");
var heightInput = document.getElementById("input-option1232");
document.getElementById("input-option1228").onchange = function(){
waistDiv.style.display = (this.selectedIndex == '1144') ? "none" : "block";
waistInput.style.display = (this.selectedIndex == '1144') ? "none" : "block";
hipDiv.style.display = (this.selectedIndex == '1144') ? "none" : "block";
hipInput.style.display = (this.selectedIndex == '1144') ? "none" : "block";
heightDiv.style.display = (this.selectedIndex == '1144') ? "none" : "block";
heightInput.style.display = (this.selectedIndex == '1144') ? "none" : "block";
}
});
```

Comment: so do you wanna apply css for the options?

Comment: Yes. through javascript.

Comment: can you please elaborate your question, what do you really want to achieve?

Comment: I want to add dependent option for products. I have purchased a plugin called related option but that plugin is not working properly with the theme. The think is when I select a option it should show two text fields, two radio option fields. But shows radio fields alone. I want to display text fields too.  So I wrote seperate javascript to show text fields. But the option ids are not same for each products, ids for these options are different in all products. Client have 500 products nearly in website. How can I add this display:block script for all products??

Comment: So I need global ID or class for these options.

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked a few times here:
[Opencart how to related 2 options in a product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529169/opencart-how-to-related-2-options-in-a-product) and 
[How to add sub options in Opencart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45720646/how-to-add-sub-options-in-opencart/45755102)

Summary: use an extension that handles "dependent/related options".

Comment: Sorry I don't need this.. I already used an extension called "related/dependent options opencart 3.x". That is not working properly.

Comment: To say "That is not working properly" is not helpful. Please explain exactly what you want to achieve?